# If $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=4$ then $(a+2)(b+2)\geq cd$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $a,b,c,d$ be real numbers with $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=4$. Prove that $(a+2)(b+2)\geq cd$.

**My approach:** I have considered an expression $$\begin{aligned}(a+2)(b+2)-cd=&4+2(a+b)+(ab-cd)\\=&(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)+2a+2b+(ab-cd)\end{aligned}$$ I was trying to write it as the sum of squares but I failed.

Can anyone show how to solve this problem please?

Comment: On AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1681175p10718473 – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24(a%2B2)(b%2B2)%5Cgeq%20cd%24)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because by AM-GM $$(a+2)(b+2)=ab+2(a+b)+4=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}(2ab+4a+4b+4+a^2+b^2)+2-\frac{1}{2}(a^2+b^2)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}(a+b+2)^2+2-\frac{1}{2}(a^2+b^2)\geq$$
$$\geq2-\frac{1}{2}(a^2+b^2)=\frac{1}{2}(c^2+d^2)\geq |cd|\geq cd.$$

Comment: How it follows that $\frac{1}{2}(a+b+2)^2\geq 2$?

Comment: @ZFR  It was typo. I fixed. See now.

Comment: Really nice and elegant solution. Yesterday i was trying to solve in this way but to be honest right noe I see that I was really close :) thank you!

Comment: @ZFR  You are welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Using the AM-GM inequality, we have
$$(a+2)(b+2) = \frac{4-a^2-b^2-c^2-d^2}{2}+\frac{(a+b+2)^2}{2}+\frac{c^2+d^2}{2}$$
$$\geqslant \frac{c^2+d^2}{2} \geqslant cd.$$